# Editable Background Images in Mailchimp

Tags: css, html-email, mailchimp

Trying to code an email template for Mailchimp, and I'm trying to be able to edit the background image tag of a  via Mailchimp itself, so I dont need to go and change the code each time I want to send it out.

Is there a way to declare the background tag as an /@*editable*/ region so I can change thethe url in mailchimp? If so, how would I go about doing it?

Current code:

```
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrap banner3" style="border-collapse: collapse; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-image: url(https://gallery.mailchimp.com/78524444e0a13e2b163d98bed/images/135974c9-84e6-4f03-9fde-891a893c58a8.jpg); background-color: #24272c; background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" background="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/78524444e0a13e2b163d98bed/images/135974c9-84e6-4f03-9fde-891a893c58a8.jpg">
```

What Im hoping to do:

```
/**
* @tab Background Images
* @section Event Image
*/

/*@editable*/ Var event-bg-img = "https://gallery.mailchimp.com/78524444e0a13e2b163d98bed/images/135974c9-84e6-4f03-9fde-891a893c58a8.jpg"

[...]

<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrap banner3" style="border-collapse: collapse; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-image: url(event-bg-img); background-color: #24272c; background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;" background="event-bg-img">
```

Obviously looking for a solution that is supported across the ridiculous amount of email clients.

Comment: Not possible according to Mailchimp support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of the MailChimp editor (as of Feb 26, 2015) does allow for making editable `background-image` properties (sorta). The following code in your HTML template:

```
/*@editable*/background-image:url();
```

will produce an editable field like this:

[image]

By adding a URL to your background image the image will appear in your template.

For example:

```
url(http://placehold.it/350x150)
```

[image]

This would require you to upload the background image to MailChimp, then grab the URL and paste it into `url()`, so it's not ideal. For intermediate to advanced users this solution might work well however.